# Guidance on how to set validations correctly with a has_many :through relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've set up three models: User, List, and UserList -- the latter being the join model between User and List, in a `has_many_through` relationship.

I'm trying to set up what I think should be fairly vanilla uniqueness constraints -- but it's not quite working. Would appreciate your guidance / advice please!

### Technical details

I have 3 models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_lists
  has_many :lists, through: :user_lists, dependent: :destroy
End

class List < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_lists
  has_many :users, through: :user_lists, dependent: :destroy

  # no duplicate titles in the List table
  validates :title, uniqueness: true
End

class UserList < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :user

  # a given user can only have one copy of a list item
  validates :list_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
end
```

As you can see, I'd like List items to be unique, based on their title. In other words, if user Adam adds a List with title "The Dark Knight", then user Beatrice adding a List with title "The Dark Knight" shouldn't actually create a new List record -- it should just create a new / distinct UserList association, pointing to the previously created List item.

(Somewhat tangential, but I also added a unique index on the table since I understand this avoids a race condition)

```
class AddIndexToUserLists < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_index :user_lists, [:user_id, :list_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

### Here's where things are going wrong.

As user Adam, I log in, and add a new title, "The Dark Knight", to my list.

Here's the controller action (assume current_user correctly retrieves Adam):

```
# POST /lists
    def create
      @list = current_user.lists.find_or_create_by!(list_params)
    end
```

This correctly results in a new List record, and associated UserList record, being created. Hurrah!

As Adam, if I try to add that same title "The Dark Knight", to my list again, nothing happens -- including no errors on the console. Hurrah!

However -- as user Beatrice, if I log in and now try to add "The Dark Knight" to my list, I now get an error in the console:

`POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/lists 422 (Unprocessable Entity)`

### My debugging and hypothesis

If I remove the uniqueness constraint on List.title, this error disappears, and Beatrice is able to add "The Dark Knight" to her list.

However, List then contains two records, both titled "The Dark Knight", which seems redundant.

As Adam, it seems like perhaps `current_user.lists.find_or_create_by!(list_params)` in my controller action is finding the existing "The Dark Knight" list associated with my current user, and realising it exists -- thereby not triggering the create action.

Then as Beatrice, it seems that the same controller action is not finding the existing "The Dark Knight" list item associated with my current user -- and therefore it tries to trigger the create action.

However, this create action tries to create a new List item with a title that already exists -- i.e. it falls foul of the List.rb model uniqueness validation.

I'm not sure how to modify that find_or_create_by action, or the model validations, to ensure that for Beatrice, a new UserList record / association is created -- but not a new List record (since that already exists).

**It feels like maybe I'm missing something easy here. Or maybe not. Would really appreciate some guidance on how to proceed. Thanks!**

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you passing as list_params?

Comment: Additionally, what exactly is your rails server console saying the error is? The http error is never very helpful in debugging

Comment: Your code ending with `End` is not valid Ruby code.

Comment: @sawa would you mind explaining why it's not valid Ruby code? Am finding the learning curve on Ruby / Rails quite steep, bit of a noob here.

Comment: I believe their point is the capital E in end makes it not a correct end keyword for Ruby, but I'd just guess this was from copying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm 99% certain that what's happening is `current_user.lists.find_or_create_by` will only search for List records that the user has a UserList entry for. Thus if the List exists but the current user doesn't have an association to it, it will try to create a new list which will conflict with the existing one.

Assuming this is the issue, you need to find the List independently of the user associations: `@list = List.find_or_create_by(list_params)`

Once you have that list, you can create a UserList record through the associations or the UserList model. If you're looking for brevity, I think you can use `current_user.lists << @list` to create the UserList, but you should check how this behaves if the user has a UserList for that list already, I'm not sure if it will overwrite your existing data.

So (assuming the << method works appropriately for creating the UserList) your controller action could look like this:

```
def create
    @list = List.find_or_create_by!(list_params)
    current_user.lists << @list
end
```

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: I did make two modifications. Not entirely sure **why** they work though -- and not sure they warrant a new question - but wondering if you / others do? 1.a) with `current_user.lists << @list`, if Adam tries to add the same title twice, I get a browser dev console error the second time: `POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/lists 422 (Unprocessable Entity)`. Rails console shows: `UserList Exists (0.4ms) SELECT 1 AS one FROM "user_lists" WHERE "user_lists"."list_id" = $1 AND "user_lists"."user_id" = $2 LIMIT $3... Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)`

Comment: 1.b) if I change this to `current_user.user_lists.create(:list_id => list.id)`, if Adam tries to add the same title twice, I **don't** get an error in the browser dev console the second time, and rails console shows: `UserList Exists (0.3ms) SELECT 1 AS one FROM "user_lists" WHERE "user_lists"."list_id" = $1 AND "user_lists"."user_id" = $2 LIMIT $3... Completed 204 No Content in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)` ---> am I missing some basic understanding of how the two different methods work, such that one reports an error while the other does not?

Comment: Other modification: in my User.rb model, I added a `-> { distinct }` option. My controller "get / index" action actually pulls additional columns from the join model (`current_user.lists.joins(:user_lists).select('lists.*, user_lists.id as user_lists_id, user_lists.rating as rating`), and it seemed that that was resulting in both "The Dark Knight" entries being returned for a single user.

Comment: So 1a is what I was saying about my uncertainty with how it would handle if the UserList already exists. It seems it doesn't handle that too well, so you'd either have to check for it's existence first or do it a different way. You may be able to circumvent this with something like `current_user.lists << @list unless current_user.user_lists.exists?(list_id: @list.id)` which won't add it if the UserList already exists.

Comment: 1b, if you change it to `create!` instead of just `create` I believe it should raise an error. This is the usual convention used by active record, the version of a method ending with a `!` raises errors, while omitting the `!` the method will just return nil if the task fails. The omitted `!` methods are useful for when you don't want a failure to interrupt the flow of code execution. If you change it to the `!` method, I imagine you'd see an error code on the browser side. Leaving it as `.create` I believe should suit your needs, but if you want a UserList to be returned use `.find_or_create`

Comment: As for the other one, I'm not sure what you mean by the added "distinct" thing, where did you add it? The join from the lists collection will join ANY UserList with the given List item as an association, regardless of user since you didn't specify the user anywhere for that table. Not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve with that query, but you should be able to do `current_user.user_lists.joins(:lists).select(...)`, and that will restrict to the user_lists for the current user and select the appropriate lists as well.

Comment: An alternative option for that query is just to add a where clause `.where("user_lists.user_id = ?", current_user.id)` and that should only include UserLists for the current user. I think you can also maybe do a merge like `current_user.lists.join(:user_lists).merge(current_user.user_lists)...` and that will similarly restrict the user lists to only the ones that would be returned by the `current_user.user_lists` query (but it would still all be contained in a single DB query)

Comment: Thanks again @obermillerk. Totally understand 1.a and 1.b -- appreciate you taking the time to explain to a noob.

I'm not quite getting what's going on with #2, but I think it's (again) exposing that I don't quite understand what rails is doing under the hood. But prob best for me to pose a new question rather than try to shoe-horn it in here.